# How to check if the record exists in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am working on a attendance system. This is the backend where i want to check if an employee with that id exists in the database. It doesnt seem to work this way. 
I am sending the data to mongodb, and each emp has different ID. Before adding a new employee, I want it to check if the employee or record already exists.

```
def checkEmployee(self):
    """
    Check if employee exists with the ID.
    Returns true if employee exists.
    :rtype: object
    :return:
    """
    result = collection.find_one({"emp_id": self.emp_id})
    # result is none means employee does not exist.
    if result is None:
        return False
    return True




def addUser(self, first_name, last_name):
    """ Add user to the database,
    Employee is already initialized with an emp_id. Use this method to add it to the database.
    """
    if self.checkEmployee() is True:
        return "Employee Exists"

    if collection.find_one({"emp_id": self.emp_id}) is None:

        # Userdata to be added to database.
        userData = {

            "emp_id": self.emp_id,
            "first_name": first_name,
            "last_name": last_name
        }
        result = collection.insert_one(userData)

        # If data is successfully updated, Returns True else Returns False .
        if result.acknowledged:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        print("Employee Already Exists with ID: ", self.emp_id)
```

Comment: why don't you add a `unique` index on `emp_id` and handle insert `error` if you receive a `dup_key error` when inserting

Comment: Can you store `emp_id` in `_id` instead?

Comment: @Messa Each employee within the organization has a seperate empID according to their designation. So in this i am having two IDs, One is emp_id and other one is _id. How would that help tho ?

Comment: @HannanMustajab: If you could provide a sample document with a little bit of more details that would be helpful.

Comment: @AbhinandanKothari 

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0248721c9d4400001a2244"
    },
    "emp_id": {
        "$numberInt": "1234"
    },
    "first_name": "Hannan",
    "last_name": "Mustajab",
    "penalty": [
        ["10/25/19", "10/21/19", "10/28/19", ""]
    ],
    "offDay": {
        "$numberInt": "3"
    },
    "attendance": [{
        "date": "2019-10-20",
        "location": "AMU",
        "time": "19:23:26"
    }]
}

Answer (score 0):

As you are not adding "_id" to userData it is being automatically generated by MongoDB. You can use the "_id" field to store your Employee Id and as "_id" is always unique in every collection you can ignore to check if a document already exists or not and directly use update operation along with upsert=True option, that will allow updating your employee document if it exists otherwise it will simply insert that document to the database.

```
userData = {
        "first_name": first_name,
        "last_name": last_name
}
collection.upsert_one({ "_id": self.emp_id }, { "$set": userData }, upsert=True)
```